Double-tap on touchpad doesn't work in QEMU Debian
I have Debian on host machine with qemu installed and debian as guest OS. lxde is used both on the host and guest.
Touchpad shows strange behavior, after booting up the VM double tap on touchpad works fine for 1-3 times and then stops working. When tapping fast multiple times only the first tap is recognized (i discovered this by using web sites for mouse click testing)
Mouse double clicks, mouse multiple clicks, and the touchpad left button click work fine except multiple taps on touchpad.
Any ideas how to fix it?
I'm ready to provide any additional information if you need
virt-manager VM xml:
<domain type="kvm">
  ....
  
  <devices>
     ...
  
    <input type="keyboard" bus="ps2"/>
    <input type="mouse" bus="ps2"/>
    <graphics type="spice">
      <listen type="none"/>
      <image compression="off"/>
      <gl enable="yes" rendernode="/dev/dri/by-path/pci-0000:00:02.0-render"/>
    </graphics>
    ....    
  </devices>
</domain>


Problem solved by starting Qemu VM using CLI. Seems like virt-manager was the cause of the problem
